# sed how to use () and \1 like sed -r '/(0-9)* .*/s/\1/2/g'

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace some 3th column like 2th.

but first I want know can we using () in address?
like

```
sed -r '/(0-9)* .*/s/\1/C/g'
```

if can't 
 what's Solution in sed can do this

```
before

cat test
1 2 3
1 2 2
2 2 3
2 2 2

after

cat test
1 2 3
1 2 C
2 2 3
2 2 C
```

Comment: are you interested especially in sed or awk/perl are fine too?

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK

```
$ awk '$2==$3{$3="C"};1' test
1 2 3
1 2 C
2 2 3
2 2 C
```

Using Perl:

```
perl -nae '@F[2]="C" if @F[2]==@F[1]; print(join(" ", @F), "\n")' test
      ^^^ Evaluates first argument as perl code
      || Split lines into array @F
      | Read line for line
```

Answer (score 0):

the `(0-9)*` is not the regex you are looking for. Also the usage of sed is not correct. Please read regex tutorial and sed's man page.

You cannot let sed in  `s/../../` reference the group in address. You have to define the group in `s/.../.../`

If you want to change the last field depends on the 2nd last field's value, awk is easier(more straightforward):

```
awk '$NF==$(NF-1){$NF="C"}7' file
```

With sed it is also possible:

```
sed -r 's/(\S+)\s\1$/\1 C/' file
```

They work no matter how many columns in your file.